# clipboard history using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipboard

I am tying to access the clipboard contents using python. I am using the below python script to perform the action.

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
result = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
print(result)
```

The above snippet helps in fetching the contents that are available in the clipboard currently. My requirement is to fetch the clipboard history completely.

Any suggestions regarding this will be really helpful.

Comment: The clipboard doesn't have history on most systems.

Comment: @mbvee You mean if I copied something It will be saved To a text file?

Comment: As Dan said, there's no way to get history that isn't persisted in some way to begin with. You'd have to have your code watch the clipboard for changes and stow those changes away to keep your own history.

Comment: N.B. that `r.clipboard_get()` is identical to your code (and throws the same error if nothing is on the clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

Use the external module called `pyperclip`

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy("abc")  # now the clipboard content will be string "abc"
text = pyperclip.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
```

[Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) | [Github](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)

Answer (score -1):

pyperclip is a great for copying from and pasting to the clipboard.

`import pyperclip
result = pyperclip.paste()
print(result)`